# Sharding Shpere setActualDataNodes {0000..1023}

Tags: groovy, spring-jdbc

I am new to Shardingjdbc. My actual tables are user_0000, user_0001..user_1024. So I use the following pattern.

```
result.setActualDataNodes("ds0.user_${0000..1023}");
```

but I always get user_0, user_1, user_2 ..user_1024

Could anyone help to solve this? I also try to use

```
result.setActualDataNodes("ds0.user_${\"0000\"..\"1023\"}");
```

It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem.

maybe you can try this:

```
result.setActualDataNodes("ds0.user_000${0..9},ds0.user_00${10..99},ds0.user_0${100..999},ds0.user_${1000..1023}"};
```